# Mapbox Navigation is avoiding roads

Tags: navigation, mapbox

I'm working on a navigation app that takes visitors on a guided tour of my farm. Initially, the roads of the farm didn't exist on Google maps or OSM, so I mapped them out on OpenStreetMaps. The updated map is visible and I can see the farm roads in Mapbox. The problem is that Mapbox navigation is ignoring the roads that I've added while generating routes - it's treating them as if there are no roads there. If I set my origin or destination inside the farm, the points get mapped to the closest previously existing road. In OSM, the entire area is inside the farm's commercial area. All the roads have their allowed access of all set to yes, and the others as unspecified. Another thing that may be of importance is that the roads are unpaved but motorable. Why is the route generating algorithm ignoring the farm roads?

[image: Ignoring the farm and farm road that I have added]

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely due to the fact that Mapbox uses 2 sets of data in this case.

Map Tiles: The [map tiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/) are building the map you can see. These are generated from OSM map tiles.

Routing Tiles: These are also build from OSM but not as frequently updated as the map tiles.

--> For the region you have mapped in OSM, the map tiles and the routing tiles are inconsistent. You can either wait until Mapbox updates the routing tiles (this can take a couple of weeks), or reach out to Mapbox Support and ask when this will happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Moritz. I believe both tiles should have been updated since I gave it 2 weeks time to update. However, I'll keep this in mind next time I make a change.

Answer (score 0):

FIX:

There was some problem with the roads I added on OSM. Maybe because it was an unpaved road, it ignored it thinking it's not motorable I guess. The fix was since it was recognising the previously existing road (Given in the image of my question), I just set all my roads values to the same as that road. And voila! It works now.

However, I'm unhappy with this fix since I'm uploading fake data to OSM (saying the road is paved even though its not) - however, it should be fine since it'll only be used by the visitors of my farm.